# Recreate active directory from scratch

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Recently we were hit with ransomware and my two domain controllers had the NETLOG and SYSVOL folders encrypted and now my group policies and scripts won't work. The users computer that infected our server had highest admin rights, which I want to restructure, so the domain controllers can't be hit again among other things. But my question is I have several pc's that log into our work domain and I want to fix the DC's to get me back to where I was and then create better backups. Both my DC1 and DC2 are on windows server 2012 VM on ESXi. I did have VM backups (which were also hit on my backup server), and I don't believe there was a windows backup role initially installed, so I don't believe I can do an Authoriative restore.

So my thought was I would spin up two new DC's and recreate all users and policies from scratch, but I'm concerned on how to make the switch without interruption, or something going wrong and nobody can log in and I'm stuck with a mess. I do have a couple applications that depend on Active Directory, so I'm hoping there is an easy way.

Thoughts on the best way to proceed? I am very new at administrative tasks, so I'm learning what I can, so please don't be to harsh, I want to fix things and make our domain more secure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have valid backups of at least one Domain Controller then there's no way to recover the domain. You'll need to build a new one from scratch and join all of the domain clients to the new domain.

Your AD dependent applications will need to be reconfigured.

Comment: So if I just just duplicate it using exact domain, then will the other PC's link right back up like nothing had changed? I'm sure passwords will need to be reset?

Comment: what happens to my folders I have set for permissions and shared with active directory groups if I recreate them? If I name everything the same will it take right off and work as expected?

Comment: To both of your questions: No. The old domain is gone. You will need to join the domain clients to the new domain. They will not "sync" up. You will need to recreate your Security groups and reapply permissions to your shared folders using these new Security groups.